# Ошибка сохранения проекта на yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Я пишу один проект на *Yii2*. Всё было хорошо, пока мне не начало выбивать, при сохранении, ошибку сохранения "Cannot Save Files", и создает два файла...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать ? Как с этим бороться ?

P.S.  Ошибку выбивает в *PhpStorm*, *Brackets*, *NetBeans*...

Comment: к сожалению, вряд ли мы сможем вам чем-то помочь, не видя ваш код; если его много, почитайте статью [mcve], а ещё гляньте общие инструкции по нахождению ошибок https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142

Comment: Может у вас прав доступа не хватает для сохранения файла(ов). Или файлы заняты другим приложением (антивирус их проверку делает).

Comment: какая ОС? и в какой директории лежит папка проекта?

Comment: У меня Windows 10, и локальный сервер - Wampserver. А на счёт кода, возможно я ошибаюсь, но не совсем важно, ибо на хосте я дописал нужный код, всё работает. А на локальном я создаю хотя бы $a = 10;, сохраняю, и уже выдаёт ошибку...

Comment: Проблема не в коде в файле, а в доступе к файлу. Где у вас лежит файл на локальной файловой системе или на удаленном сервере и вы его редактируете через ФТП или SSH.